# Why does this loop only reads in the first txt file correctly?

Tags: r, file, import

```
ep_dir <- "C:/Users/J/Desktop/e_prot_unicode"
```

## reading and merging data

```
# reading the data. empty list that gets filled up

ep_ldf<-list()

# creates a list of all the files in the directory with ending .txt

listtxt_ep<-list.files(path = ep_dir, pattern="*.txt", full.names = T) 

# loop for reading all the files in the list

for(m in 1:length(listtxt_ep)){
  ep_ldf[[m]]<-read.table(listtxt_ep[m],fill=T,header=F,sep = "\t",stringsAsFactors=FALSE) 
} 

f_ep = "C:/Users/J/Desktop/e_prot_unicode//05AP.U1"

#reading and merging the files, data.table is then called d_ep

d_ep = data.frame()
for(f_ep in listtxt_ep){
  tmp_ep <- read.delim(f_ep,row.names = NULL,sep = "\t",fileEncoding="UTF-16LE",fill = T) %>% as.data.frame(stringsAsFactors = F)
  d_ep <- rbind.fill(d_ep, tmp_ep) 
}
```

I want to read in a bunch of txt files. The above code reads in the files incorrectly. Only the first one (05AP.U1) contains all values properly. All the others are missing the values in the first column (here I do not mean the numbering row), that are the names. Why does this code only reads in the first file correctly?

Comment: Do all the files looking the same? Since your are already working with a list try `lapply(listtxt_ep, function(x) read.table(x, fill=T, header=F, sep = "\t", stringsAsFactors=FALSE))`. The output can be summarized using `dplyr::bind_rows()`

Comment: This gives me one column with the directory paths of the files. @Roman

Comment: try `x <- listtxt_ep[1]; read.table(x, fill=T, header=F, sep = "\t", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)`. When this is not working, then your path is not correct.

Comment: actually x gives me one column with the file path. I am pretty sure my path is correct. With the code of the question the first file is correctly read in-  @Roman

Comment: then `read.table(x, fill=T, header=F, sep = "\t", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)` should read your table. If there is an error, please paste it in the comments

Comment: @Roman As you see in the code of my question I want to read in multiple txt files (with a loop) Unfortunately only the first file is read in completely and the others are incomplete

Comment: then you have to debug your code. Read only one of the incomplete files. Then you have to optimize the `read.delim` part as long as the file is read in completely. After having foud out whats the problem in some files you have to "say" your loop that for some files you need another read function using an e.g. `if(x == file_incomp)` statement.